# How to share data between users of a website in real time?

Tags: optimization, chat

I'd like to make a simple web interfaced chat program between users of site. How is this commonly implemented?

The first thing that comes to mind is to assign a unique chat session id to both users and then keep polling the database for new messages. But this seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are two techniques you can use to accomplish good communication between your server and the clients. You can use either [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/) for browsers that support it. (Normal chatapplications generally use sockets as well.) However, WebSockets are very new, and older browsers don't support it yet (and even new ones don't always support it, or have it disabled by default). You can use a technique named [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to accomplish the same thing.